Why freezegun.freezetime affects code outside of the freezetime context
Can anyone help me, how can I use freezegun to freeze time only in one request?
@router.get('/debug')
async def debug_route(request):
    debug_datetime = request.headers.get('Debug-datetime')
    with freezegun.freezetime(debug_datetime, real_asyncio=True):
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        # some logic with debug time ...
        print(dt.datetime.now(), 'debug datetime')


@router.get('/real')
async def real_route(request):
    real_datetime = request.headers.get('Real-datetime')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(dt.datetime.now(), 'real datetime')

I want freezegun to freeze time only in /debug route. But when debug_route is executing. I get debug datetime in my real_route.
Thank you, for answers.
I want freezegun to freeze time only in specific route without affecting other routes.
I need all my code in the debug route to override calls to functions like datetime.now without affecting other requests.
